# Any impact of I change owner of a Windows system folder?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, permissions

If I change the owner for a folder under `C:\windows\system32` to Administrator, will there be any negative impacts to system and application funtionality?

Comment: Which folder? Better yet, why not start by telling us you feel it's necessary to change the ownership in the first place?

Comment: C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc, and it is necessary because my application needs to access read/write HOSTS file under this folder. Any impact you think if I change owner to an administrator account which my specific application runs on?

Comment: That should be safe enough but I'm always nervous about software that wants to change the hosts file. Use DNS instead if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks John! I am testing against DNS using my specific application, so...

About your conclusion -- "should be safe", could you provide why you make such conclusion please?

Comment: Is this program released to anyone else other than so? If so you should clearly point out your doing this in case it is causing issues, and if possible try find another way to do.

Why does you application need both read and write access to the hosts file anyway?

Comment: why are you not just granting rights to that specific file and not the folder?

Comment: "Is this program released to anyone else other than so" -- just run in my private intranet servers to do some network problem analysis utility (diagnose network issues, like DNS issue). In this case, any impact if I change the owner of etc folder?

Comment: Hi Antitribu, I want to keep it flexible and extensible in the future to grant permission once on folder and if I need to access other files in etc folder (in the future), I do not need to grant again. In my scenario, any impact if I change owner of etc folder?

Comment: "eed both read and write access to the hosts file anyway" -- I write it to test some ability of resolve address locally other than from DNS. After test, I will recover HOSTS file original content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "feature" you're butting heads with is [Windows Resource Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc185681(VS.85).aspx), added initially in Windows Vista. In this case, it's an ACL that, in previous version of Windows, granted "Administrators" "Full Control" permission but, in Vista and newer versions, prevents "Administrators" from modifying the ACL on the "%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc" folder itself.

Odds are good that making the change in ownership, so long as you don't mess with the "SYSTEM" and "TrustedInstaller" permissions, probably won't cause operational issues. I just verified with a Windows 7-based PC that HOSTS-based name resolution continues to work with the owner of the "...\etc" folder changed to "Administrators" and the "Administrators" permission set to "Full Control".

I've read your other questions, and I see that you're trying to manipulate the HOSTS file programmatically. I'd *strongly* caution you not to do what you're trying at all. In this day and age, there's no good argument for using HOSTS file-based name resolution for *anything*. Run a DNS server and make your changes there. If you need to "override" your production DNS for a "test environment" put up a second DNS server that hosts authoritative zones for any RRs that need to be "overridden".

You can "diagnose DNS issues" with tools like "nslookup", win32 ports of [dig](http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/), and sniffers. Using HOSTS file-based name resolution isn't a useful method for "diagnosing DNS issues".

Making this change to stock folder permissions puts your machine(s) into a non-default state that Microsoft may not test for in deployment of future updates. While things appear to "work" today that's no guarantee that future updates won't cause problems because of assumptions in system folder permissions that such updates might make.

Comment: Cool, question answered!